# What is the exact meaning in C++ of these escape sequences (\n, \t, \v) in comments?

Tags: c++, escaping, comments

I was reading through the [Working Draft](http://isocpp.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2021/n4892.pdf) of C++ and was surprised when I came across the seemingly simplest feature of programming: Comments! (and even more surprised that I didn't find anything about the behavior of escape sequences in comments!)

**Quote from the C++ draft**:

> If there is a *form-feed* or a *vertical-tab character* in such a comment, only whitespace characters shall appear between it and the new-line that terminates the comment; no diagnostic is required.

I struggle in what exactly is meant by this quote.

I came up with this:

```
// This is a comment\f \tThis is still part of the comment\nThis is not part of the comment
```

As it seems, escape sequences have influences on comments, so I played around with it for a while but didn't come to a major conclusion.

```
// This is a comment\nThis is not part of the comment
```

As they say in the draft:

> which terminates immediately before the next new-line character

So I figured, if I just put a newline character in the comment myself, the rest of the comment doesn't get treated as a 'comment'? But it kind of does..? What is the deal with that?

Comment: Did you put a newline character in the comment, or did you put a \ character followed by an n character?

Comment: @NathanPierson I did it exactly as shown in the examples above.

Comment: Okay, so you didn't put a newline character in the comment yourself. The [escape sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) apply to string and character literals. Comments are neither.

Comment: Those aren't form feeds or vertical tab characters, those are backslashes with other characters after them.

Comment: What do they mean in the draft then? Could you give an example?

Comment: @Eldinur They mean form feed and vertical tab characters--they're ASCII (or whatever) codes. Like `0x0B` in the file (vt)

Comment: @DaveNewton Ah ok I understand now, thanks. So the literal escape sequences are meaningless in comments?

Comment: The [escape sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) apply to string and character literals. Comments are neither. *(I stole the previous comment.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "If there is a form-feed or a vertical-tab character in such a comment, only whitespace characters shall appear between it and the new-line that terminates the comment; no diagnostic is required."

This talks about *literal* form-feed and vertical-tab characters, not escape sequences (which are not interpreted in comments).

A valid comment:

```
// comment<a literal vertical-tab><whitespaces...><newline>
```

Also valid:

```
// hello\f\f\f\fworld<newline>
```

Here's an invalid comment, because the vertical-tab is followed by something else than only whitespace characters before the newline:

```
// comment<a literal vertical-tab><whitespaces...>FOO<newline>
```

Comment: @Nelfeal Oups, typo and copy-paste error. Fixed. Thanks.